# What is the price of deploying an ERC-721 token contract on the main net?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a few questions regarding the deploy to the main net. They are mostly about the cost of it. Im using `hardhat` and `ethers.js` for deployment. The contract itself is written in `Solidity`.

1. Could you please provide me with the exact pricing for deploying the smart contract? I found out that its basic fee of 21k gas + 32k of some contract creation fee. Then theres the price for kbs of the contract. But the kbs are what Im not so sure of. On every site they state a different price for kb of compiled bytecode of my contract. Could you please provide me with the gas price for kb in 2021?
2. Where can I found my compiled bytecode size - the size that determines the pricing? When I compile my code with hardhat it produces a bunch of `.json` files in the `artifacts` folder. I am really struggling to understand which one is the compiled contract bytecode that will be stored on the blockchain and that I will pay for.
3. How can I set gas prices in `ethers.js`? In every tutorial or example that I saw, nobody sets gas prices manually in `ethers.js`, not even a gasLimit. Is `ethers.js` setting these prices by itself? And are the prices that `ethers.js` sets good or are they unnecessary high? Or is there a way to set the gas price in the `hardhat` config file?
4. Which amount of eth would you guess that my deployment to the main net will take? My contract is written in `Solidity`, it uses the classic `openzepellin` libraries for `ERC-721` tokens. I put everything into just one `.sol` file and it has 1.4k lines.

Comment: deploy the contract on a test net, see how much gas it consumes on etherscan (Gas Used by Transaction), then check the current gas price on the main net https://etherscan.io/gastracker (you need it in WEI) and multiple both to get the amount of ether to deploy your contract with that gas price.

Comment: If you are asking these questions, I think you are doing something wrong. NFT costs a few hundred USD to deploy. Developing it costs hundreds of times that. And sales should be hundreds of times that.

Comment: @MajdTL Thanks for replying. So I already deployed my contract on rinkeby and this is the transaction: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4ae4a748130be88d333839a33abda3db8c326c3f3deb33d6f33f055cfbe55fe7. So as I understand the relevant field is Gas Used by Transaction, which shows 3.6mil. Is this Gas Used by Transaction identical across all the networks? Will the deployment of this exact contract cost the same 3.6mil on the main net?

Comment: @WilliamEntriken what do you mean doing something wrong? I just dont understand where should I get some info about the prices of deploying my contract. And I also dont understand how to set the gas price or gas limit in hardhat or ethers.js. Or even if I should set these prices manually at all. Maybe its just better to let the ethers.js count these prices for me. Which I dont know therefore I am asking these questions. On the other hand Im quite familiar with the ERC-721 standard and solidity so I had enough skill to write and test the contract

Comment: Answer WITHOUT any warranty: It will consume the same amount of gas if you do exactly the same process (if price 60 gwei then you need probably 0.25 ether). Another solution for you, you can copy your contracts to remix and **BE CAREFUL** (make sure you are using the correct compiler+optimization and imported dependencies of openzeppelin (you cant use @Openzepplin, you need to get them from Github using correct tag&version) then connect your metamask to remix and click on deploy, then metamask will pop up and ask you to confirm (DONT CONFIRM), and you can see how much is estimated to pay

Comment: @WilliamEntriken I think the gas config in hardhat and ethers is not well documented and not easy to understand after the London upgrade, it would be great if you or someone write a blog or make a video about it :)

Comment: @MajdTL I see, thanks for the "gas used" hint on the transaction. The only question thing that is still not so clear for me is how ethers.js does the pricing. Does it offer the price in gwei for gas based on the actual prices of gas? Or is it better to set that by myself somehow? It would be really helpful if you know more about that question too.

Comment: i have sadly no answer for that. There should be a way to set max price to pay. If u find something let me know or ask another question specifically about hardhat / etherjs gas config after London upgrade for mainnet :)

Comment: @MajdTL Thank you, I'll plan on doing this for my Open Source Community Service Hours livestream